# Find co-ordinates where LineString intersects a Polygon border in turfjs

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turfjs

Is there a way in Turfjs to determine the co-ordinates at which a LineString intersects with the border of a polygon?

There's a number of ways to find out if a point is within a polygon and a number of ways to find out if a point is on a line and so on, but I can't seem to figure out a way to ask **"at what point does this line intersect this polygon's border"**.

I could enumerate the points in the polygon using a line intersection algorithm to find that point but I was wondering if there's a more "turf" way of doing this.

For context, I've loaded a GPX track and want to estimate the location/time at which the track enters/exits a defined area.

Because a GPX track only records locations at specific intervals it usually the case that pN recorded at time tN is outside the area and pN+1 recorded at time tN+1 is inside the area.
If I can get the point at which line (pN, pN+1) intersects the polygon's border I can estimate the exact time the track crosses into the polygon.

Comment: You may want to consider asking this at gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks @SteveBennett, I've asked over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, turfjs does not seem to have an API for doing this.

I was able to get the answer I wanted by enumerating the points in the polygon from the GeoJSON object to construct a sequence of line segments and then I used [maxogden/geojson-js-utils](https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils) `linesIntersect` function to test for intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Turf function that does exactly that, but there is [intersect](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-intersect), which finds the area of intersection between two polygons.

You could:

1. Construct a polygon by joining the line to itself reversed (so ABC becomes ABCBA)
2. Find the [intersection](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-intersect) of ABCBA and P, the original polygon using Intersect.
3. The intersection should be a zero-area polygon that is the part of ABCBA inside P. Somehow compute the length of it (strangely there's no perimeter function).
4. Subtract that length from the [original length](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-line-distance) of ABC.

Not exactly elegant, true. :)

EDIT

Tried this. Turns out Turf-intersect doesn't return intersections if one of the polygons is zero-area.

Comment: I _think_ that [turf-line-to-polygon](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-line-to-polygon) could do this. Then you could buffer it by a small amount so that the polygon is not empty. I'll play around with it and see what kinds of results it gives.

Comment: Yeah, I see there are lot more Turf modules in that Github organisation than the "official" list: https://github.com/Turfjs

Comment: @SteveBennett can you check here, please,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974083/attempting-to-a-configurable-attribute-of-a-configurable-property-issue-in-turfj

Comment: I don't see any relevance to this question, other than that both use Turf.